# from codeigniter query to javascript log

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i need to pass a query from my codeigniter to javascript console log in-order to view my data in a javascript so i have my model

```
public function getChartData()
{
    $this->db->select('Month,Completion_Percentage');
    $this->db->from('monthlyreport');
    $this->db->order_by('Project_No', 'asc');    
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    $data_List = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) 
    {
    $data_List[] = $row->Month;
    $data_List[] = $row->Completion_Percentage;
    }
    return $data_List;

}
```

my controller:

```
public function monthlyReport()
{
    $this->load->view('monthlyReport');
}
```

and internal script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function){
        $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '<?php echo site_url('main/chart_api')?>',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        } 
        });
    }
```

where it should go:

```
public function chart_api()
{
    $data_List = $this->foo_pro->getChartData();
    echo json_encode($data_List);
}
```

and it shows a console error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

You nedd to add of dataType:"JSON" in Ajax, and

```
you have echo json_encode($data_List); 
not return json_encode($data_List);

$.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        dataType:"JSON",
        url: '<?php echo site_url('main/chart_api')?>',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        } 
        });
```

Comment: @Hanthony Tagam.what output are you getting from this method chart_api(); Plz paste here.

Comment: @Hanthony Tagam you have echo  json_encode($data_List); not  return json_encode($data_List);

Comment: i think site_url wont load my controller because it wont change in load

Comment: @HanthonyTagam if you have index.php in url you should use site_url otherwiser you can use base_url();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151907/discussion-between-hanthony-tagam-and-whoami).